# laravel 10 php artisan storage:link problem in my live app on plesk / unix enviroment images will not show via symlink

Tags: laravel, laravel-breeze

i have installed laravel 10 as of july 2023, and i have installed breeze and then created a CRUD and Image Upload app

i have followed along with the guide [Laravel 10 CRUD and Image Upload Tutorial with Laravel Breeze and Repo Example](https://fajarwz.com/blog/laravel-10-crud-and-image-upload-tutorial-with-laravel-breeze-and-repo-example/#create-textarea-input-component)

i have now tried doing this 3 times and eveything works ok, apart from the display of the images from the uploaded post(s), i am guessing its something to do with the command

php artisan storage:link

the images are being uploaded, i can see them in the directory

public
storage
images
posts
featured-images
NE3chyoFJVASXGGzw6vaxiSfxXNi9KCN2Z0Z3hef.jpg

and my image link generated in laravel isis

https://plwd.com/shopshare/storage/images/posts/featured-images/NE3chyoFJVASXGGzw6vaxiSfxXNi9KCN2Z0Z3hef.jpg

a Symbolic Link should have been created from the public/storage folder to the storage/app/public folder when i ran the command  - php artisan storage:link i have unchecked the box in plesk on my domain to Restrict the ability to follow symbolic links, so this should not be the issue

what am i missing here, the website is hosted on plesk in unix enviroment

i have tired starting over again from the start, and everytime, i end up with the same problem as images not diplaying

Answer (score 0):

When you run command for linking storage in Laravel it creates symbolic link "storage" inside the "public" folder of your project. If you check the public folder there you should be able to see a symbolic link for "storage" folder. The problem here might be that you already had linked storage while you were working in your localhost. It means that the symbolic link has been created in your local machine and that's why it is not working on your production server. Try first removing the symlink "storage" from "public" folder of your project:

```
rm public/storage
```

then rerun command for linking storage again but through ssh connection to your server as the symbolic link should be generated in server and not your localhost:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i didn't create it on localhost, i have done a new install of laravel via ssh on my unix/plesk server. i have also deleted it all and tryed over a few times and its still not working 

i have tryed rm public/storage, and recreating the link with php artisan storage:link, but still its not working

Comment: this seems to have fixed the problem

Comment: @CHLOEHARLOW did it help? Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: i have found the issue was very simply, i forget to change the app url in the .env file

i was using localhost, instead of the website url, which of course caused the error, a simple oversight